# tabs with slide left right

Tags: jquery, slider

i made one tabs everythign is ok.. but i can't make slide left/right. mainly i want to slide animation like http://www.slidetabs.com/. Any idea how? Check out my code at http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYTW/1/

Below is my js code:

```
initHomeTabs=function(){
    //click Event for all tabs: 
    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        $(".tab").css('display','none');
        $(".tabs li").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected')
        $('#'+this.childNodes[0].href.split('#')[1]).slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    })
    //set first tab active
    $('.tabs li').eq(0).click();
}

// call above function on dom ready event
$(document).ready(function(){
    initHomeTabs(); 
});
```

Comment: Any answer you find will be based roughly on this site: [Learning JQuery - slide elements in different directions](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

Comment: I made some progress, but it's far from complete: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXYTW/2/).

Comment: thanks reichard. i checked.. its work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQK9f/1/)**

Try this. I have edited your code

Add this to your head tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.tabs li a ', function () {
    $(".tabs li").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest("li").addClass('selected')
    var panel = $(this).data('href');
    $.scrollTo(panel, 400);
});
});
```

### html code

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="Appointments" class="tab">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</div>
    <div id="Enews" class="tab">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,.</div>
    <div id="Brochure" class="tab">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</div>
</div>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a data-href="#Appointments">Appointments </a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-href="#Enews">Enews </a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-href="#Brochure">Brochure </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

### stylesheet

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.content div {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:25px;
    left:0px;
}
#Appointments {
    left:0px;
}
#Enews {
    left:100%;
}
#Brochure {
    left:200%;
}
.tabs {
    margin-left:10px;
    position: fixed;
}
.tabs li {
    background:none;
    background:#736c61;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none
}
.tabs li.selected {
    background:#e3d5af;
    top: -1px;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs li.selected a {
    color:white;
}
.tabs li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tab {
    background:#e3d5af;
    color:#312822;

    border: 1px solid #756e64;
}
```

Here is the working fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQK9f/1/)**  .Hope this helps

Comment: changed the script file to be added to the head.check it out. and wrap the js code inside $(document).ready(function()